# install Linux on iMac G5

Tags: unix, powerpc, g5

Is there a Linux distribution, that runs on an old iMac G5 with a PowerPC processor? I would like to use the old iMac as computer for my mother, she would only need an up-to-date browser running, nothing more.

I found [MintPPC](http://www.mintppc.org/), based on the Debian "testing" branch. Would that work?

---

I am installing mintPPC right now with [this installation instruction](http://www.mintppc.org/content/installation-instructions-mintppc-11). It seems to work fine.

Comment: According to the documentation on the website, G5 is supported. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to install linux on the old mac so I can use it just as an internet-access also with a new flash version inside the browser

Answer (score 1):

Debian is probably your best choice. The problem is that the Flash Player situation would be worse on Linux than on Mac OS X. There is no official Flash Player for Linux PPC. There are some alternatives, though, described in [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Flash.2C_Flash_video.2C_Gnash_and_Lightspark). [This page](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/powerpc/) has an **extremely** detailed guide on installing Debian for PowerPC. Also, [this page](http://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/inst/install) describes which macs are compatible with Debian PPC. Oh, and yes, MintPPC would work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin). It works well for old iMacs, if you use the right PowerPC installer.

For help, go to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ

For downloads, go to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

Answer (score -1):

I have a Mac G5 as well. I have run Lubuntu on it for some time. It is a light weight version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Maybe you could add some links to your answer (just edit it again to do so) to make it more useful for future visitors?